# Separate a dummy variable column into two columns with summary statistics

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have what should be a simple question, but I cannot figure out how to achieve the desired result in dplyr/tidyr.

I have just computed a summary dataframe like so:

```
results <- df_long %>%
  group_by(question,imputed_liberal, question_text) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(score, na.rm = T), Reaction_Time = mean(reation_time, na.rm = T), Number = n())
```

Each question is repeated in two rows, one for imputed_liberal = T, and one for imputed_liberal = F, and columns for accuracy and reaction_time.

```
   question imputed_liberal question_text Accuracy Reaction_Time Number                                                         

 1 10       F               How many...    0.750       61.4     16
 2 10       T               How many...    0.429       55.9     14
```

I would like to collapse both of these rows into a single one (so one row per question) with columns "conservative accuracy" (imputed liberal = F), "liberal accuracy", "conservative reaction time" and "liberal reaction time."

I figured that `spread` was the right approach, but have not been able to figure out how to spread on two values (accuracy and reaction_time).

my attempt:

```
results <- results %>% 
           filter(!is.na(Accuracy)) %>%
           spread(results, key = imputed_liberal, value = c(Accuracy, Reaction_time))
```

Throws an error because you cannot have two values in spread.

Comment: If you make your example easily reproducible you have higher chance of getting good answers. dput() can hel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the standard `tidyr` way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(-Number) %>%
  mutate(imputed_liberal = ifelse(imputed_liberal,1,0)) %>%
  gather(,,Accuracy, Reaction_Time) %>%
  unite(key,key,imputed_liberal) %>%
  spread(key,value)

#   question question_text Accuracy_0 Accuracy_1 Reaction_Time_0 Reaction_Time_1
# 1       10   How many...       0.75      0.429            61.4            55.9
```

You can also nest first so there's less gymnastics to do :

```
df %>%
  select(-Number) %>%
  nest(Accuracy, Reaction_Time) %>%
  spread(imputed_liberal,data) %>%
  unnest(.sep = "_")

#   question question_text FALSE_Accuracy FALSE_Reaction_Time TRUE_Accuracy TRUE_Reaction_Time
# 1       10   How many...           0.75                61.4         0.429               55.9
```

Comment: The second one works well!  For the first one I'm getting the error: "  Column `imputed_liberal` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable."  What is the double commas doing in the gather command?  No matter how long I use the tidyverse, it always seems like magic...

Comment: double comma means i'm keeping the default values for the first two parameters and i'm too lazy to type them, it would be the same if i wrote `gather(key,value,imput`

Comment: normally you can just skip default parameters altogether and name the ones you'll use, but here the following parameters are destined to the `...` arguments, which can't be named

Comment: your table is probably grouped from a past operation, use `ungroup` before my code and it should work.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks a bunch.  For some reason the second strategy eliminates "question_text" as a column.  Do you know how to bring it back from within the piping chain?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but maybe you used a transmute call after the grouping ? grouping columns are kept automatically but you'd have to add the column to the instruction yourself if you ungrouped before.

Comment: Ah, great call.  You were right --- I needed to ungroup from the earlier grouping call.

Answer (score 1):

One option is that you subset in 2 parts and join those 2 parts together.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(filter(results, imputed_liberal), 
    filter(results, !imputed_liberal), by="question") %>%
     select(-Number.y)
```

**Result:**

*Note:* One can rename columns per their choice.

```
# question imputed_liberal.x question_text.x Accuracy.x Reaction_Time.x Number.x imputed_liberal.y question_text.y Accuracy.y Reaction_Time.y
# 1       10              TRUE     How many...      0.429            55.9       14             FALSE     How many...       0.75            61.4
```

**Data:**

```
results <- read.table(text =
"question imputed_liberal question_text Accuracy Reaction_Time Number  
1 10       FALSE               'How many...'    0.750       61.4     16
2 10       TRUE               'How many...'    0.429       55.9     14",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```